# Search Core Data Users By Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, core-data

I am trying to get a list of users whose names were selected from a tableview and stored in the array selected.

What's wrong with my code? Sorry this is my first time with CoreData so I don't really know what's wrong.

```
NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AUser"   inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
for (id a in selected) {
   NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@",a]; //each user has a name attribute
   [request setEntity:entity];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];

   NSError *error = nil;

   NSArray *array = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
   //This array is always empty! Why? What am I doing wrong with the request
}
```

Tell me if you require any more info/further explanation.

Other things to note - there are no warning/error signs - all variables not declared here are declared elsewhere

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First, check the `error` parameter to `executeFetchRequest:error:`, there's a good chance it's trying to tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: How do I do that? I get an error when I call NSLog(executeFetchRequest:error);

Comment: Just log the error itself, not part of the method name. `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);`

Comment: My output: `Error: (null)`

So it thinks there is no error?

I call this right after I declare NSArray *array

Comment: And that's after executing the fetch request?

Comment: Yes, I placed it in my code on the last line before the closing bracket in the example above

Comment: @tom-harrington Is there anyway to see a database of my AUser class - I want to check if the AUser objects are being initialized properly?

Comment: I use Core Data Editor (which is in the Mac app store) but you can use SQLite at the Mac OS X command line. Or, just try fetching with no predicate and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not getting any error response, an empty array means that the fetch completed successfully but that it didn't find anything satisfying your predicate. In your code that then implies that `selected` does not contain values for `name` that can be found in your data store.

Your code seems to assume that `selected` is an array of `NSString`s which match the `name` value of some of your stored objects. If that's not the case-- if it contains something other then `NSString` maybe-- an empty set is to be expected. The fact that `a` is declared as an `id` makes me wonder what's really in there.

Comment: Selected is an array of strings. I looked at my database from the terminal sqlite3 tool, it seems that my Models are properly initialized, just no objects are being created for some reason, although I do have some code that is supposed to do this. Nevertheless, you did your best with the code that was given here, so here treat yourself to a chocolate chip cookie!